# Cannot connect localhost Evebox on docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, suricata

I use docker-compose to start Evebox, but I cannot connect it on localhost:5636.

A part of my docker-compose file :

```
evebox:
   image: jasonish/evebox:master
   volumes:
     - /var/log/suricata:/var/log/suricata
   links:
     - elasticsearch
   networks:
     - elk
   ports:
     - 5636:5636
   command: --input /var/log/suricata/eve.json -e http://192.168.32.15:9200


 elasticsearch:
   image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.1
   container_name: elasticsearch8
   environment:
     - cluster.name=docker-cluster
     - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
     - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
     - "http.cors.enabled:true"
     - "http.cors.allow-origin:\"*\""
   ulimits:
     memlock:
       soft: -1
       hard: -1
   ports:
     - 9200:9200
   networks:
     - elk
   restart: always
networks:
 elk:
```

I cannot connect Evebox on localhost:5636, but I can connect it when I use `docker exec -it 2c50f02b7385 /bin/sh` to get into docker container.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: That sounds like a symptom of the process inside the container listening on `localhost` and not `0.0.0.0`.  Does it print out some information like "listening on localhost:5636" in its logs when it starts up?  Can you include the actual bit of your application source code that starts listening for network connections?

Comment: Yes, I've checked the log in Evebox docker container, and it does print out "Listening on [127.0.0.1]:5636". Can I modify the source code in Evebox docker container ?

Comment: Does it really work if I do modify the source code in docker container ?

Comment: You'd have to change your application's source code to fix this and run `docker build` to get a new image, then re-run the `docker-compose up` command.  Any change you make to files inside the container will get lost as soon as the container is deleted and recreated.

Comment: @cyberlinlin, looks like some formatting issue in your `docker-compose` file, I am trying to reproduce issue but gettting ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 1, column 1
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 14, column 2 error

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
expose:
  -"5636"
```

in your configuration, like this!

```
evebox:
   image: jasonish/evebox:master
   volumes:
     - /var/log/suricata:/var/log/suricata
   links:
     - elasticsearch
   networks:
     - elk
   ports:
     - 5636:5636
   expose:
     - "5636"
   command: --input /var/log/suricata/eve.json -e http://192.168.32.15:9200
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

EveBox, as of 0.11 binds to localhost by default instead of 0.0.0.0. When running inside Docker you will need to give it a host to bind to access it from outside the docker image.  This can be done with the `--host` parameter.

For example:

```
   command: --input /var/log/suricata/eve.json --host 0.0.0.0 -e http://192.168.32.15:9200
```